Resulting distribution from the difference of two independent bivariate normal distribution
Given two independent normally distributed random variables $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ we can show
$$
X-Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_1-\mu_2,~\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)
$$
I’m looking for the 2D version. Namely, for two independent bivariate normal distributions $\boldsymbol{X}=\begin{bmatrix}X_1\\X_2 \end{bmatrix}\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_1, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1)$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}=\begin{bmatrix}Y_1 \\ Y_2\end{bmatrix}\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_2, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_2)$ with 2x2 covariance matrices $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_2$, what is the distribution for $\boldsymbol{X}-\boldsymbol{Y}$.

Hint: mulivariate normal distribution is completely defined by expectations and covariances between all possible pairs of its components.

Welcome on MSE. For a $n$-dimensional generalization, you could write $X-Y$ as $[I_n;| ; -I_n]\left[\begin{array}{c}X\\hline Y\end{array}\right]$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

I think this post has the answer in the original question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22879

The following proof may not be the most simple/efficient, yet it exploits some useful tricks concerning multivariate Gaussian distributions.

Lemma 1. If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\Sigma_X)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$ are two independent Gaussian vectors (with respective dimensions $n$ and $p$), then their concatenation
$$C(X,Y):=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}X_1 & \dots & X_{n} & Y_1 &\dots & Y_p\end{array}\right]^\intercal$$
is a $(n+p)$-dimensional Gaussian vector, with parameters
$$\mu:=C(\mu_X,\mu_Y)\quad\quad \Sigma:=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}\Sigma_X & \mathbb{0} \\\hline \mathbb{0} &\Sigma_Y\end{array}\right]$$
proof. Every linear combination $L$ of the components of $C(X,Y)$, can be written as the sum $L_1+L_2$ of a linear combination $L_1$ of the components of $X$ and a linear combination $L_2$ of the components of $Y$. $X$ (resp. $Y$) is gaussian implies $L_1$ (resp. $L_2$) follows a normal distribution. $L_1$ is $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$-measurable, $L_2$ is $\sigma(Y_1,\dots,Y_p)$-measurable and these $\sigma$-algebras are independent. $L=L_1+L_2$ follows a Gaussian distribution as the sum of two independent normal variables. We showed that every linear combination $L$ of the components of $C(X,Y)$ is normally-distributed, therefore $C(X,Y)$ follows a multivariate Gaussian distribution. It is easy to check that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are the parameters of this distribution.

Lemma 2. If $X$ is a $p$-dimensional gaussian vector (with parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$) and $A$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, then $AX$ follows a $n$-dimensional Gaussian distribution (with parameters $A\mu$ and $A\Sigma A^\intercal$).
proof. Every linear combination of the components of $AX$ is also a linear combination of the components of $X$, hence $AX$ is a gaussian vector. By linearity, its expected value is $A\mu$. For the covariance matrix:
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(AX)&=\mathbb E\left[\left(AX-\mathbb E[AX]\right)\left(AX-\mathbb E[AX]\right)^\intercal\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[A\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\left(A\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\right)^\intercal\right]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[A\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\left(\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\right)^\intercal A^\intercal\right]\\
&=A\mathbb E\left[\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\left(\left(X-\mathbb E[X]\right)\right)^\intercal \right]A^\intercal\\
&=A\text{Cov}(X)A^\intercal=A\Sigma A^\intercal
\end{align*}

We can now state our $n$-dimensional result!
Proposition: If $X$ and $Y$ are independently normally-distributed vectors, then $X-Y$ is a gaussian vector, with parameters
$$\mathbb E[X-Y]=\mathbb E[X]-\mathbb E[Y]\quad\quad \text{Cov}(X-Y)=\text{Cov}(X)+\text{Cov}(Y)$$
proof. Write $X-Y$ as $[\;\text{I}_n\;|\;-\text{I}_n\;]C(X,Y)$ where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$, and apply both lemmas.

An illustration: (in dimension $n=2$)

from left to right,

the probability density function of $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\Sigma_1,\mu_1)$ with $\Sigma_1=\text{I}_2$ and $\mu_1=\boldsymbol{1}$.
the probability density function of $Y\sim\mathcal{N}(\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ with $\Sigma_2=\text{I}_2+\frac{1}{2}J_2$ ($J_2$ is the $2\times 2$ exchange matrix) and $\mu_2=-\boldsymbol{1}$.
the probability density function of $X-Y$.

